# Issue with formula that retrieves column from one excel if isblank or the same column in another excel if not

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I need to get a formula that let me:

If excel0.column1 doesn´t have any concordance with excel1.column1 --> get excel2.column12.

If excel0.column1 have any concordance with excel1.column1 --> get excel1.column12.

I coded this formula and it looks like is working, but for some values from excel1, retrieves #N/A. That happens when it doesn´t exists in excel0 any value of excel1.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP(A3;'[Referencia1 - Masters Changes'!$A$2:$L$14100;12;FALSE));

VLOOKUP(A3;'[Referencia2 - Masters Changes'!$A$2:$L$13502;12;FALSE);

VLOOKUP(A3;'[Referencia1 - Masters Changes'!$A$2:$L$14100;12;FALSE))
```

Comment: the Vlookup will return `#N/A` if a value is not found. Maybe `ISERROR` is what you are looking for?

Comment: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3;'[Referencia1 - Masters Changes'!$A$2:$L$14100;12;FALSE);VLOOKUP(A3;'[Referencia2 - Masters Changes'!$A$2:$L$13502;12;FALSE))`

Comment: Try `=IFERROR(FirstVlookup,SecondVlookup)`. What is your excel version? If you are on O365 then you have many dynamic formula to handle this.

Comment: Thanks you all for your help. It is working. Just for a double win, I am setting a zero in the worst scenario,. How can I set empty instead? Many Thanks